# How to solve ADB unauthorized in RECOVERY mode

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to authorize the device while it's in Recovery Mode?

My device has Marshmallow 6.0 and is authorized in normal boot mode, but unfortunately, it can't be authorized when reboot to recovery.

When i type in Recovery

```
adb shell
```

it keeps saying:

```
 error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

Searching the web didn't give a valuable response.

Regards

Comment: the stock Android recovery does not support any `adb` commands besides `adb sideload`. SE is not a right forum for discussing problems with 3rd party software (unless it's a development tool)

Comment: ok, thanks, will post it on Android Enthusiasts

Answer (score 0):

You can get that error if your platform-tools are not with the latest version